# Is it normal my whole React App is refresh after each change url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My  component at the top level is refreshed every time i change URL (using React Route v6).

I didn't expect that, i would think only the new page component should be invoked, is it normal?

Here is my top level React App:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
        <RecoilRoot>
          <App />
        </RecoilRoot>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And here is the  component (i see the log every time i change url using the React Router Link component):

```
function App() {
  console.log('REFRESH APP !');
  
  const location = useLocation();
  const isAuthenticated = useRecoilValue(isAuthSelector);

  const routing = useRoutes(routes(isAuthenticated, location));
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      {routing}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Not sure it is directly related, but here is how i expose the routes:

```
const routes = (isLoggedIn:boolean, location:LocationState) => {
  const redirectUrl = location?.state?.from?.pathname || "/";

  console.log('REDIRECT URL = ' , redirectUrl)

  return [
    {
      path: '/login',
      element: isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to={redirectUrl} /> : <Login />,
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      element: isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to={redirectUrl} /> : <Register />,
    },
    {
      path: '/forget-password',
      element: isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to={redirectUrl} /> : <ForgetPassword />,
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      element: isLoggedIn ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }}/>,
      children: [
        { path: '/profil', element: <Home /> },
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```

Here is how i use the Link component to change the URL:

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Link from "@mui/material/Link";

<List>
              {
                props.links.map( ({path, label}, index) => 
                  <ListItem key={index}>
                    <Link component={RouterLink} to={path}>{label}</Link>
                  </ListItem>
                )
              }
</List>
```

Comment: You are console logging as an unexpected side-effect, so the behavior is a bit "undefined" since React can call the `App` function any number of times it needs to. Move any console logs into an `useEffect` hook so see how often a component is *actually* rendered ***to the DOM***. How are you updating the path? I don't see any `Link` components being rendered. If you are manually updating the URL then the page/app will reload.

Comment: I have updated it, i see the 2 console.log "REFRESH APP !" after every click on a Link

Answer (score 0):

Using the **useHistory** hook from `react-router` redirects to paths without re-rendering the page. If you're using `react-router@6` or higher, use the **useNavigate** hook instead of useHistory.

```jsx
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

This example is more for your case.

```jsx
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();

const routes = (isLoggedIn:boolean, location:LocationState) => {

    return [
    {
      path: '/login',
      element: isLoggedIn ? history.push(redirectUrl) /> : <Login />,
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      element: isLoggedIn ? history.push(redirectUrl) : <Register />,
    },
    {
      path: '/forget-password',
      element: isLoggedIn ? history.push(redirectUrl) : <ForgetPassword />,
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      element: isLoggedIn ? <Home /> : history.push("/login"),
      children: [
        { path: '/profil', element: <Home /> },
      ],
    },
  ];
};
```

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6`, so there is no `useHistory` hook. This code is invalid since the `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, not the result of navigation function.

Comment: in that case use the **useNavigate** hook instead of useHistory.

Comment: No, for the reason explained in the second sentence of my comment. See [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes) docs for usage.

Comment: then maybe it doesn't work for a reactnode function but i've used this in a component type route with an inner function to decide to go to a route or to redirect somewhere else. and this has worked just fine for me.

`<Route

{...rest}

render={props => {

return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> :  history.replace('/login') >

</ Route>`

Comment: Then you've lucked out. (1) That is all RRDv5 syntax and component API you are referencing, and (2) You *should* have been rendering a `Redirect` component instead of invoking the `history.replace` function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, the issue is not the <Navigate> component since i have this refresh using the <Link> component